# Getting the LOCATION of an imported target (Qt5) gives me what symlinks points to and not the symlink itself

Tags: qt, cmake

I am having issues with getting the location of Qt libraries. Let's take libQt5Core. If I run `ldd libQt5Core.so.5.11.3`, I get `libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f19750ae000)`. However, when I do  the following:

```
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Gui REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
get_target_property(importedLocation Qt5::Core IMPORTED_LOCATION)
get_target_property(location Qt5::Core LOCATION)
message(STATUS "IMPORTED_LOCATION = ${importedLocation}")
message(STATUS "LOCATION = ${location}")
```

I get:

```
IMPORTED_LOCATION = importedLocation-NOTFOUND
LOCATION = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.11.3
```

Here's my problem, I `ldd` shows that `Qt5::Widgets` depends on `libQt5Core.so.5`, which is a symlink to `libQt5Core.so.5.11.3`. Due to packaging reasons, I am taking all external `.so`s that I need for my project and copying them into my binary folder. The problem is that what currently happends is that I copy `libQt5Core.so.5.11.3` instead of `libQt5Core.so.5` because this is what `LOCATION` is giving me. This fails because later, `libQt5Widgets.so.5.11.3` will try to find `libQt5Core.so.5`, which is not there.

So, my question is how can I get that symlink, `libQt5Core.so.5` instead of the actual library file pointed? I want to get the symlink of an imported target, but it's giving me what the symlink resolves to.

Comment: "If I run `ldd libQt5Core.so.5.11.3` ..." - Do you mean `ldd libQt5Widgets.so.5.11.3` instead? Otherwise it is strange that `ldd` on a library outputs that library as one of its entry. As for `LOCATION` property, it reflects the library which you otherwise need to **explicitly** link when use Qt5Core. This property has nothing common with RPATH entries embedded to other libraries: those entries are **implicitly** "linked" when link with that libraries. It seems that you need to collect RPATH entries other than LOCATION properties.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes sorry, that's what I meant. I am new to CMake and have a hard time finding anything property related to `rpath` online. Is there a property for what you are suggesting?

Comment: Sorry, RPATH was wrong term for what `ldd` outputs. More correctly to name them as "shared library dependencies". As I said before, these dependencies are part of the library file and used **implicitly**  by the linker. Because of that CMake doesn't track them. You need to collect these dependencies with help of other tools. E.g. with `objdump -p /path/to/program | grep NEEDED` as suggested in `ldd` manpages.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for the suggestions! It's a shame there isn't an integrated way to do this with Cmake.